# Filling dropdownlist with json oobject but it is not working

Tags: asp.net, json

[Code Sample JSon i am not getting dropdownlist value properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfw4v.png)

Comment: image file is there of json code..please find error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code while appending the options in the select list .

```
$('#mySelect').append($('<option>', { 
        value: item.value,
        text : item.text 
    }));
```